# Is Oracle Apex suitable for a near BI web app?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have been developing with Laravel 5 and mostly MySQL database, however I have basic knowledge of Oracle DB (never used it before in a project). Recently, our company one me to work on a system with spec as follows:

- We want all data to be in a central DB (Currently, there is a lot of Excel around). I expect the web app to have every huge forms just looking 
  at the Excel samples.
- Employees in different department (about 14), will come in and log into the app and complete web forms (each department has it's web form format). The submitted data in different units will have to be validated by different managers in the unit before it can be made available to the reporting department for analytics.

Oracle BI solution would be adopted in the near future, so what I am to develop now is just a temporal solution. Is Oracle apex suitable for this kind of project? Management want to see some UI.

Comment: Looks you got the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say yes, but I'm biased as I have been working with APEX for about 10 years now.  However it sounds ideally suited to this.  Since this is a temporary solution you don't need to worry too much about Javascript, AJAX or CSS - just use the latest pre-defined APEX theme and build pages using APEX built-in forms and reports. You may need to write some PL/SQL if your pages do more processing than simple create/update/delete on tables.

A possible issue if you think you will have very big forms: APEX allows a maximum of 200 updatable input fields per page (it used to be 100 in older versions).

If you haven't already, get yourself a free account on [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com) where you can experiment, and also can play with some of the packaged applications to see what APEX can do.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Tony Andrews. On the excels presented to me, there are a lot of formulas, which management would like to have that incorporated later on, to this new web app. That's, for different input fields, when the user enters values, some kind of ajax-like calculation should be done and presented. With what technology can I do that in Apex?

Comment: You can learn APEX pretty fast if you already know Oracle and PL/SQL, probably faster than any other UI tool.  Of course like anything it takes a while to know it well.

Comment: In APEX you would use a "Dynamic Action" that is triggered by a change to an input value and calls (via AJAX) a PL/SQL function or procedure to perform the calculation and update other fields (or refresh a whole region of data).